# environment path for all users

Tags: linux, centos, path

I'm trying to add an environment path `/usr/pgsql-9.5/bin` for all users on my CentOS 7 system.

I created a new file under `/etc/profile.d/`

It looks like this:

```
export PATH="/usr/pgsql-95/bin:$PATH"
```

I then restart the system and login using root.

I type in `echo $PATH`, it lists

```
/usr/pgsql-9.5/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
```

So everything is correct for root user.

I then type

```
sudo su postgres 
echo $PATH
```

It lists:

```
/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

`/usr/pgsql-9.5/bin` is missing?

Why is the path not added for user `postgres`?

If I create a new user the path is correctly added `$PATH`.

Comment: Try `sudo su - postgres`, which will run the login process for postgres (see `man su`).

Comment: Curiously , in my mind using `sudo su postgres` is fine while root had export environments variable `PATH`. i think you need double check what if user 'postgres' recover the profile. and if you have `postgres` 's password? try `su postgres` then put `echo $PATH`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using su not su -l

Using su -l will provide environment like direct login and it will set environment variable mentioned by you in /etc/profile.d/filename

Try

```
 sudo su -l username
```